# When would you use InnoDB PAGE compression over InnoDB TABLE compression?

Tags: mysql, innodb, compression

From what I understand, InnoDB table level compression is "transparent" and appears to perform well on the surface.

In what circumstances would it be beneficial to choose InnoDB page level compression?

Comment: I prefer having the client compress the columns that are likely to be compressible.

Comment: @RickJames fair enough, I agree. But that's most often not viable after the initial design and release).